# Override Date Object in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datetime

We need to override the Date object to the server date and time in Angular 7.
As an example,

If we are use new Date() need to return the server date and time instead of the Current date and time.

Comment: It would make a lot more sense to leave built–in objects alone and create a *getSeverDate* function that does want you want. If clocks on the server and client are set to the same date and time, then a Date created on either at the same instant will have the same time value, the only difference is when you get local values from each system. If you know the offset for the server, you can generate timestamps for it on any other system regardless of its offset.

Answer (score 2):

add overrideNewDate method to AppModule and call it in it's constructor

```
export class AppModule {


  constructor() {
    this.overrideNewDate();
  }

  overrideNewDate() {
    Date.prototype.toJSON = function (key) {
      //return what you want
      return '25/01/2021';
    }

  }

}
```

so if you log `console.log(new Date())` you'll get:

```
25/1/2021
```